# Running empty program in Eclipse takes ~10 Mb. Why?

Tags: java, memory

In Java, this program:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

simply sleeps for 7 seconds while I run it in Eclipse and check the System Monitor to see that it holds ~10Mb of memory. Running the program in terminal without Eclipse also takes 10Mb.

For what those megabytes are reserved?

**Env**:
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.3.3.2.fc17-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jvm internally manages memory. There are many things loaded when an application is started. Furthermore jvm gets memory from the OS pre emptively so that there is a smaller overhead when creating new objects.

This [article](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp) covers some of the aspects jvm memory usage .

Excerpt :

The allocated memory is an overall amount of memory allocated by the JVM, while used memory is the amount of memory which is actually in use.

Answer (score 1):

That memory is used to load up your program and other related classes, Java Runtime, libraries et al. Your program uses Thread, String, Exception, which in turn use many other classes. Considering that, 10Mb is really less.

Comment: Don't forget the JVM itself - if I understand you are checking used memory in Linux's System Memory Monitor.

Comment: @Cebence Exactly. The JVM is going to allocate itself a decent amount of memory so that it does not have to request it on-demand every time that an allocation is performed by your program. You will have to look in a Profiler to see actual usage.